# Multiple Buttons or Links in a cell?

Tags: buttons, tables, data-tables

I am trying to find out what the best approach in term of UX that a cell can have two buttons that associate with Sessions or Calls in each Date columns?

The value of Links/Buttons are the total of Sessions and Calls in each date column.

I have came with with two ideas, is there a better approach?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there a relationship between session and calls? Like calls per session or sessions per call??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily have to go with a button but as a user, I'd definitely like a click target that's bigger than a single number. You could make the whole cell clickable.

If you want buttons you could make your header "Sessions/Calls" and then use a single cell and make a [button group](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups) with sessions on one side and calls on the other.

The "right" answer here may depend a bit on existing standards within your app. Do you already have lots of links or buttons in tables within your app? Are these acting more like links or buttons (navigation vs performing an action)?